# Why am i getting the wrong output

Tags: java, string, hex, int

i wrote a program to convert a hexadecimal number to its equivalent binary form using the following code but i got wrong results. The code is as follows:

```
public String convert(String num){
    String res="";
    int []hex={0000,0001,0010,0011,0100,0101,0110,0111,1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110,1111};
    int i;
    char ch;
    for(i=0;i<num.length();i++)
    {
        ch=num.charAt(i);
        if(ch>='a' && ch<='f'){
            res+=hex[ch-97+10]+"";
        }
        else if(ch>='A' && ch<='F'){
            res+=hex[ch-65+10]+"";
        }
        else if(ch>='0' && ch<='9'){
            int d=ch-48;
            res+=hex[d]+"";
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

If i give the sample input as "12ae" then i get the corresponding output as "1810101110".
It happens only(goes wrong) when there is a number in the input field and works fine for all characters only. But when i change the array named hex to that of a String type it gives me the exact answer.

Is it because the compiler treats the numbers in the integer array as some form of octal numbers or is it because of some other reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with the octal numbers. The following declaration:

```
int []hex={0000,0001,0010,0011,0100,0101,0110,0111,1000,...};
```

declares an array of integers that in words, would be

```
zero
one
eight
nine
sixty-four
sixty-five
seventy-two
seventy-three
one thousand
```

and so on. This is clearly not what you want. If you declare `hex` as `String[] hex`, and use `"0000","0001",...`, then you will get the intended answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your numbers like `0010` are interpreted as octal numbers. Writing `0010` is the same as writing `8`.

You can convert to a binary string using `Integer.binaryString`.

Comment: I used that too but i wanted to represent each hex digit as 4 digits in binary form so i had to omit the method(as it wasn't giving conversions up to 4 digits).

Answer (score 0):

If you write this:

```
int []hex={0000,0001,0010,0011,0100,0101,0110,0111,1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110,1111};
```

then Java ofcourse does not automatically know that these should be interpreted as binary numbers.

Integer literals that start with a `0` are interpreted as octal numbers. Integer literals starting with `1` to `9` are interpreted as decimal digits.

If you are using Java 7, you can use the new `0b` syntax for binary numbers:

```
int[] hex ={ 0b0000, 0b0001, 0b0010, 0b0011, ..., 0b1111 };
```

Otherwise, use decimal or hexadecimal:

```
int[] hex = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 15 };
int[] hex = { 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, ..., 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF };
```

But since these are just the numbers from 0 to 15, you don't even need the array at all: because `hex[i] == i`, you could just use `i` directly instead of `hex[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers below eight are treated as octals, by the way if they didn't treated as octals 0001 would be changed to 1 and 0101 would be changed to 101, so you would loose required zeros in binary format.

By the way you can do this:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(value);
```